# How to decompile aab AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

I can not decompile AndroidManifest.xml  in aab file

I unzip aab file, and want to decompile AndroidManifest.xml in unzip files, use this command:

```
java -jar /my/tools/path/AXMLPrinter2.jar AndroidManifest.xml 
>1.xml
```

I get this error:

````
```java.io.IOException: Expected chunk of type 0x80003, read 0x4c7b00a.
at android.content.res.ChunkUtil.readCheckType(ChunkUtil.java:29)
at android.content.res.AXmlResourceParser.doNext(AXmlResourceParser.java:765)
at android.content.res.AXmlResourceParser.next(AXmlResourceParser.java:72)
at test.AXMLPrinter.main(AXMLPrinter.java:43)```
````

I find file type is Android binary XML in old apk of AndroidManifest.xml , but in aab is data

Answer (score 7):

Decompiling the AndroidManifest.xml can be done with the official google bundletool

`bundletool dump manifest --bundle bundle.aab`
If it prints it on stdout you can do this:
`bundletool dump manifest --bundle bundle.aab > AndroidManifest.xml`

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Answer (score 1):

Try this given decompiler [BundleDecompiler](https://github.com/TamilanPeriyasamy/BundleDecompiler)

```
de-compile option:

    java -jar BundleDecompiler.jar decompile  --in=input_app.aab   --out=output_dir
```

Comment: better be aware that BundleDecompiler will delete all your file on output folder! lost all of my files cause of this